# Can this M.2 SSD suddenly fail with moved/damaged capacitor?

Tags: ssd, storage, computer-building, nvme, physical-damage

Few days ago I built a new PC and of course I had to do something wrong. In this case I rotated the in-board M.2 plastic lock in the opposite direction and was wondering why it doesn't sit well.

After I figured out that it should go in the other direction I noticed that I most likely damaged/moved that silver part (is it called capacitor?) which is visible in the attached image.

I booted the PC, installed Windows on it and everything works fine (so far). Before I booted the PC I was moving my PC from horizontal to vertical orientation and vice versa, I checked and that moved silver part is still in its place so it's not completely detached from the drive.

Should I worry about it? I know that as of now it may work fine but is there a higher chance that it will suddenly fail partly or completely? Should I perform some software scans on the drive to make sure that everything is fine? Or should I just go to some electronics service to ask them to check it out and maybe solder that part.

Sorry for my lack of HW knowledge, help will be much appreciated. Also, please let me know if it's called capacitor or is it sth entirely different.

Visible moved/damaged capacitor (or whatever it is, I'm not sure):

[image]

Here's how the drive looks like on product pages in the online stores:

[image]

Comment: If it ain't broke, don't fix it. Some capacitors are not necessary under all circumstances.

Comment: "*that silver part (is it called capacitor?)*" - It's a surface mount component. That small silver & black component could be a resistor (rather than a capacitor). Looks like your drive is missing another component below the loose one you're asking about. BTW referring to an SSD as a "*disc*" makes no sense. 'Drive' would be appropriate, since that's what the 'D' in SSD represents.

Comment: @sawdust Yeah, "disc" was a mistake stemming from the similarity of "drive" in my mother tongue and "disc" or "disk".
Which component is my drive missing besides the loose one? Do you mean the first of the three silver & black components in the lower half of the drive?

Comment: Kid of hard to envision how it could be moved to it's current position, is that half still 'attached'? You'd expect the solder joint to be broken, maybe it was like this from factory .. It's a 3 second job for someone familiar with soldering SMD components to put it back the way it's supposed to be.

Comment: "*Do you mean the first of the three silver & black components in the lower half of the drive?*" - Yes. When I blow up the photo, it looks like just two solder pads and a scrape mark between them. Why does the board look dirty, ie. brownish residue?

Comment: @JoepvanSteen Yeah, maybe it was made like this, I expected it to move when I was putting the whole PC case horizontally and vertically but it stayed in place.

Comment: @sawdust No idea, the motherboard was taken straight out of the box so it shouldn't be dirty, maybe the photo was badly exposed. I see what you mean that they don't look like they should but I didn't do anything with them so I don't know maybe I just received a faulty looking drive? Although I hope it'll work just fine.

Comment: If it was made like this then it was probably a mistake, an error while soldering the capacitor (? probably filtering capacitor) on. If it was not meant to be there it would not be there at all, not half soldered on.

Answer (score 2):

The position and tracking going to it looks like a decoupling capacitor. It is there to take high frequency noise from the connected pin, potentially caused by the power supply or the device itself, and to couple it to ground thus resulting in a slightly cleaner power supply.

The chip it connects to will have multiple power lines, all with their own capacitors working to smooth the supply at that pin. A single missing capacitor will not prevent the device from working, but it may not work *quite* as well as it should.

So long as the other capacitors are fitted you are probably fine. We tend to go a bit overboard with these things to make sure it that under worse case conditions. If the rest of the components in your system such as your power supply and motherboard are high quality and have good clean power supplies then chances are you are fine. Decoupling is usually about cleaning up a marginal supply and providing a local reservoir to deal with tiny surges.

I would expect that one single missing capacitor will not be a problem, but as always your mileage may vary.

Comment: On the other hand, a loose component could fall off and one end of it could short out something. (Bearing in mind that it is a capacitor.) Hmm, does that invalidate my earlier comment?

Comment: @AndrewMorton “On the other hand, a loose component could fall off and one end of it could short out something.” Then if that is your concern, don’t leave the dangling capacitor attached to the drive. Just remove it completely. Snip it off and toss it.